# How to populate Top navigation items to drop down control using JQuery in SharePoint?

Tags: navigation

I have a requirement, the default page have two drop down controls, I need to populate few top navigation item(Sub sites) to drop down 1 and few to drop down 2 control using Jquery or Javascript.

Could you please guide me with the  example? 
 Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get the information, how you divide it to 2 drop downs is your logic in JQuery

Navigation in SharePoint has two types.

Creating Navigation in the Quick Launch( i..e Left Navigation)
Creating Navigation in Top Navigation bar (i..e Top links on the page)
To create the above navigations we have separate endpoints respectively

QuickLaunch EndPoint :`/_api/web/Navigation/QuickLaunch`

TopNavigation EndPoint: `/_api/web/Navigation/TopNavigationbar`

Below post can give you more information on this

https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/sharepoint-2013-working-on-navigation-using-rest-api/